# Switching from global static variables to static variables breaks code

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, pthreads

I'm working on an assignment for school, one of the requirements of which is that I cannot use global variables, but I do need static variables for shared memory. The premise of the assignment is to use the pthread library and semaphores to ensure that created threads execute in reverse order. I've gotten it to work with global static semaphore/condvar/mutex as such:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM 5
static sem_t threadCounter;
static pthread_cond_t nextThreadCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t makingThreadCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t makingThreadMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t nextThreadMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *wait_func(void *args)
{
    // cout<<"Waiting"<<endl;
    // pthread_cond_wait(&makingThreadCond, &makingThreadMutex);
    // cout<<"Woke up"<<endl;
    int tid = *((int *)args);
    int val;
    sem_getvalue(&threadCounter, &val);
    // cout << tid << ":" << val << endl;
    while (tid != val-1)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&nextThreadCond, &nextThreadMutex);
        sem_getvalue(&threadCounter, &val);
        // cout<<"evaluating condition in"<<tid<<", val is "<<val<<endl;
    }

    sem_wait(&threadCounter); // decrement threadCounter
    // cout << "after decrement" << endl;
    sem_getvalue(&threadCounter, &val);
    // cout << "decremented val "<<val << endl;
    cout<<"Exiting thread #"<<tid<<endl;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&nextThreadMutex);
    // cout<<"after nextThreadMutex unlock"<<endl;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&nextThreadCond);
    // cout<<"after nextThreadCond broadcast"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[NUM];
    if (sem_init(&threadCounter, 0, NUM) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Failed to init sem" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        int *argId = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*argId));
        *argId = i;
        if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, wait_func, argId))
        {
            cout << "Couldn't make thread " << i << endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

but this isn't allowed as I said, so I tried to convert it where I share them through a struct and passed in with pthread_create arguments as such:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM 5

struct args
{
    int tid;
    sem_t* sem;
    pthread_cond_t* cond;
    pthread_mutex_t* mut;
};

void *wait_func(void *args_ptr)
{
    // cout<<"Waiting"<<endl;
    // pthread_cond_wait(&makingThreadCond, &makingThreadMutex);
    // cout<<"Woke up"<<endl;
    struct args* args = (struct args*) args_ptr;
    int tid = (args->tid);
    pthread_cond_t cond = *(args->cond);
    pthread_mutex_t mut = *(args->mut);
    sem_t sem = *(args->sem);
    int val;
    sem_getvalue(&sem, &val);
    // cout << tid << ":" << val << endl;
    while (tid != val - 1)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mut);
        sem_getvalue(&sem, &val);
        // cout<<"evaluating condition in"<<tid<<", val is "<<val<<endl;
    }

    sem_wait(&sem); // decrement threadCounter
    // cout << "after decrement" << endl;
    sem_getvalue(&sem, &val);
    // cout << "decremented val "<<val << endl;
    cout << "Exiting thread #" << tid << endl;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    // cout<<"after nextThreadMutex unlock"<<endl;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    // cout<<"after nextThreadCond broadcast"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    static sem_t threadCounter;
    static pthread_cond_t nextThreadCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    static pthread_mutex_t nextThreadMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_t tid[NUM];
    if (sem_init(&threadCounter, 0, NUM) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Failed to init sem" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        int *argId = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*argId));
        *argId = i;
        struct args args;
        args.tid = *argId;
        args.sem = &threadCounter;
        args.cond = &nextThreadCond;
        args.mut = &nextThreadMutex;
        if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, wait_func, &args))
        {
            cout << "Couldn't make thread " << i << endl;
        }
    }

    // cout << "Before posting sem" << endl;
    // sem_post(&makingThreads);
    // cout << "Sem posetd" << endl;
    // cout<<"Broadcasting"<<endl;
    // pthread_cond_broadcast(&makingThreadCond);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

This gets stuck immediately with "Exiting thread #4" twice. I would think that the second code is equivalent to the first, just without global variables but there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: What is the point of `static` before your variables? I don't see any reason for it. Note that your code looks like C, except for the use of `<iostream>`. There are several things you should not do in C++ in there: 1. there should not be a `struct` keyword before types in variables declaration, 2. you should use `new` instead of `malloc`, 3. you should use the `<thread>` library instead of pthreads directly, 4. you should use `reinterpret_cast` instead of C style casts.

Comment: You *do not* need static variables, and trying to use them is making your code needlessly complex.

Comment: It is not necessary to use static variables between threads.    Take note that the thread function accepts an argument.   In creating the thread, you can supply a pointer that will be passed to the thread function.   And that pointer can point to data .....    Also (assuming C++11 and later) there is standardised support of threads in the standard library -  it is preferable to use that rather than platform-specific APIs (like pthreads).

Answer (score 1):

```
    struct args args;
```

This declares an object inside the scope of your `for` loop. When execution reaches the end of the `for` loop, this object gets destroyed -- like any other object that's declared locally within a function or within some inner scope -- and this happens before either the loop starts again from the beginning, or if the `for` loop stops iterating altogether. Either way, as soon the execution reaches the next `}` this object goes away. It is gone for good. It gets destroyed. It is no more. It joins the choir-invisible. It becomes an ex-object.

But before that happens, before the end of this loop, the following occurs:

```
    if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, wait_func, &args))
```

So you start a new execution thread, and pass it a pointer to this object, which is about to meet its maker.

And as soon as `pthread_create()` returns, that's the end of the loop and your `args` object is gone, and the abovementioned happens: it gets destroyed; it is no more; it joins the choir-invisible; and it becomes an ex-object.

And the C and the C++ standards give you absolutely no guarantees whatsoever, that your new execution thread actually starts running, and reaches the point where it reads this pointer, and what it's pointing to, before the end of this loop gets reached.

And, more likely than not, each new execution thread doesn't get around to reading the pointer to the `args` object, in the main execution thread, until long after it gets destroyed. So it grabs stuff from a pointer to a destroyed object. Goodbye.

As such, this execution thread's actions become undefined behavior.

This explains the random, unpredictable behavior that you've observed.

The usual approach is to `malloc` or `new` ***everything*** that gets passed to your new execution thread, and pass to the execution thread a pointer to the `new`ed or `malloc`ed object.

It is also possible to carefully write some code that will make the main execution thread stop and wait until the new execution thread retrieves whatever it needs to do, and then proceeds on its own. A bunch more code will be needed to implement that approach, if you so choose.

Your code also has evidence of your initial attempts to take this approach:

```
    int *argId = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*argId));
    *argId = i;
    struct args args;
    args.tid = *argId;
```

`malloc`ing this pointer, assigning to it, then copying it to `args.tid` accomplishes absolutely nothing useful. The same thing can be done simply by:

```
    struct args args;
    args.tid = i;
```

The only thing that `malloc` does is leak memory. Furthermore, this whole `args` object, declared as a local variable in the `for` loop's inner scope, is doomed for the reasons explained above.

P.S. When taking the "malloc the entire `args` object" approach, this also will leak memory unless you also take measures to diligently `free` the `malloc`ed object, when it is appropriate to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a pointer to the local variable `args` to `pthread_create`. The variable's lifetime ends when the `for` loop iteration ends and the pointer becomes dangling.

The thread may be accessing it later though, causing undefined behavior.

You need to allocate `args` dynamically (but not `argId`), and pass that to the thread. The thread function must then assure the deletion of the pointer. Also don't name your variables the same thing as a type. That is very confusing. The `struct` keyword in a variable declaration is generally (if you don't name variables and types the same) not needed in C++ and may cause other issues when used without reason, so don't use it and name thing differently.

```
struct Args
{
    int tid;
    sem_t* sem;
    pthread_cond_t* cond;
    pthread_mutex_t* mut;
};

//...

auto args = new Args{i, &threadCounter, &nextThreadCond, &nextThreadMutex};
if (pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, wait_func, args))
{
    cout << "Couldn't make thread " << i << endl;
}
```

and at the end of the thread function delete the pointer:

```
void *wait_func(void *args_ptr) 
{
    auto args = static_cast<Args*>(args_ptr);

    //...

    delete args;
}
```

`static_cast` is safer than the C style cast, since it is much more restricted in the types it can cast between and e.g. can't accidentally drop a `const` or anything similar.

---

None of the variables seem to have a reason to be `static` either in the global or local case.

Answer (score 1):

```
pthread_cond_t cond = *(args->cond);
pthread_mutex_t mut = *(args->mut);
```

This tries to create a new condition variable and mutex and initialize it based on the value of the condition variable and mutex pointed to. That doesn't make sense and won't work.

```
while (tid != val - 1)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mut);
    sem_getvalue(&sem, &val);
    // cout<<"evaluating condition in"<<tid<<", val is "<<val<<endl;
```

Here, you pass to `pthread_cond_wait` a pointer to the local condition variable and mutex you created above rather than a pointer to the shared one. Look at this code:

```
int a;
foo(&a);

void foo(int* a)
{
    int b = *a;
    bar (&b); // If bar changes *b, that will not affect a!
}
```

See the problem? You passed `bar` a pointer to `b`, not `a`. So if `bar` changes the thing the pointer points to, it won't be modifying `a` but the local copy of `b`.

Don't try to create mutexes or condition variables that are copies of other mutexes or condition variables. It doesn't make semantic sense and it won't work.

Instead, you can do this:

```
pthread_cond_t* cond = (args->cond);
pthread_mutex_t* mut = (args->mut);
```

Now you can pass `cond` and `mut` to `pthread_cond_wait`, and you'll be passing pointers to the shared synchronization objects.